# The main page image hasn't changed

Tags: bug, support, status-completed

I felt pretty pleased with myself when I won the "Weekly Featured Image" for April 11th. Also I've been credited on the main page it's still showing last weeks image :-(

Have I missed something, or should it have rotated round by now..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your photo (excellent, btw) is now displayed in all its glory. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thanks for that Marc

Comment: @Sean don't forget to mark this an accepted answer, if you're happy with the resolution...